# reshaping (1,103,10) into (103,10) array

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have as input

```
Y =[[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 1 0 ..., 0 0 0]
  [0 0 1 ..., 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]]
```

Meaning the shape is (1,103,10)
What I want is an array of shape (103,10)

So my array should look like:

```
Y =[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 1 0 ..., 0 0 0]
  [0 0 1 ..., 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
```

How can we do this?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with ipython, but asusming it is just like regular python you can simply do: X = Y[0] which would assign the value of Y[0] (the first element of your 1, 103, 10 array into a new variable X.

Comment: Have you read about `numpy` `reshape`?  `squeeze`?  indexing?  The way you write these expressions they look like simple nested lists, but the shape values suggest they are numpy arrays.  Make sure you understand the difference, and try, where possible, to demonstrate that in your question.

Comment: @Stian V. Svedenborg your trick did it, but now i have array of shape (10,1,12) and like to have array of (10,12). Putting array[0] gives me now only shape (1,12) Can you explain or can you tell what to do to have the array with as shape (10,12)? tnx

Comment: ok solved with a reshape command (10,12)